# How to run a shell command before qt build process?

Tags: qt, gcc

I'm using Oracle Linux 6 which officially has only g++ 4.4.7 compiler. It keeps complaining

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11"
```

I found a way to get around as stated in https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/getting-a-c11-compiler-for-node-4,-5-and-6-on-oracle-linux-6. With this the complier will work in a shell if I run

```
scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

before the compiler call of g++ xxx .

So how can I setup qt so that it executes the additional command before calling the compiler? Thanks.

Comment: If the goal is to get `qmake` to use a specific compiler, you can always just set the `QMAKE_CXX` or `QMAKE_CC` variables in the project file to that compiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I add the QMAKE_CC flag to .pro and it works. As an alternative can i just add it to the "additional argument" field in "projects"->"build steps"->"qmake" section?

Comment: Why don't you just build latest gcc on your machine?

Comment: @YeP Great, glad that helped. I have no idea if the alternative you suggest will work, since I've never used Oracle Linux and don't know what IDE you're using. But if it works, it works. You can always explicitly edit the `.pro` file if it fails for some reason.